# How to automatically get mail from work Exchange server into Gmail

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, exchange, imap

My work recently turned off forwarding of email coming in to our work addresses (grrr) but I am addicted to the gmail user interface and to my collection of all my mails in gmail. Can anyone suggest how I might get all new mail coming into my work email (it's an exchange server) into my gmail account. The simple way would have been to get gmail to connect directly but unfortunately it can only use POP, and our work email server only accepts IMAP connections.

I was thinking maybe I can run some kind of client, like Outlook, which would connect to both accounts (gmail and exchange) and sync them together, but I can't see how this would work as they are separate accounts.

Someone else had a very similar problem ([Getting email from Exchange to Gmail via IMAP](https://superuser.com/questions/312038/getting-email-from-exchange-to-gmail-via-imap)) and the recommendation was to use an exchange rule to forward, but no form of forwarding works on our exchange server.

Thanks for any ideas!

Cheers,

Ben

Comment: Yes, I find the Gmail interface much better to use than Outlook. But my workplace has POP3 access. Could you possibly use a VBA solution? Of course, this would mean having to have Outlook running constantly to forward all your new mail. Not ideal.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm suffering basically the same thing now.